# Can't plot in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, latex

I have a jupyter notebook script and a part of it looks like that:

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
import scipy.stats 


df = pd.read_csv("./titanic-train.csv")

ax = df.Age.hist(bins=20)
ax.set_xlabel("age / years")
ax.set_ylabel("frequency");
```

after that i get an error and it won't print the histogram. 
I am using Python 3.7.3 installed with Anaconda. 
From printing latex in the cmd window in Windows 10 i get:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250
>   64-bit)

and here is the Error Message that I get from running the dataframe.hist():

```
Error in callback <function install_repl_displayhook.<locals>.post_execute at 0x0000029D82BD2950> (for post_execute):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex)
    303                                              cwd=self.texcache,
--> 304                                              stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    305         except FileNotFoundError as exc:

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    394     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 395                **kwargs).stdout
    396 

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    471 
--> 472     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    473         try:

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    774                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 775                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    776         except:

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1177                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
-> 1178                                          startupinfo)
   1179             finally:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in post_execute()
    107             def post_execute():
    108                 if matplotlib.is_interactive():
--> 109                     draw_all()
    110 
    111             # IPython >= 2

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_pylab_helpers.py in draw_all(cls, force)
    126         for f_mgr in cls.get_all_fig_managers():
    127             if force or f_mgr.canvas.figure.stale:
--> 128                 f_mgr.canvas.draw_idle()
    129 
    130 atexit.register(Gcf.destroy_all)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in draw_idle(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1905         if not self._is_idle_drawing:
   1906             with self._idle_draw_cntx():
-> 1907                 self.draw(*args, **kwargs)
   1908 
   1909     def draw_cursor(self, event):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    386         self.renderer = self.get_renderer(cleared=True)
    387         with RendererAgg.lock:
--> 388             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    389             # A GUI class may be need to update a window using this draw, so
    390             # don't forget to call the superclass.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     36                 renderer.start_filter()
     37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39         finally:
     40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1707             self.patch.draw(renderer)
   1708             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1709                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   1710 
   1711             renderer.close_group('figure')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    133     if not_composite or not has_images:
    134         for a in artists:
--> 135             a.draw(renderer)
    136     else:
    137         # Composite any adjacent images together

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     36                 renderer.start_filter()
     37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39         finally:
     40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2643             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2644 
-> 2645         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2646 
   2647         renderer.close_group('axes')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    133     if not_composite or not has_images:
    134         for a in artists:
--> 135             a.draw(renderer)
    136     else:
    137         # Composite any adjacent images together

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     36                 renderer.start_filter()
     37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39         finally:
     40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1204         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
   1205         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
-> 1206                                                                 renderer)
   1207 
   1208         for tick in ticks_to_draw:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer)
   1149         """Return lists of bboxes for ticks' label1's and label2's."""
   1150         return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
-> 1151                  for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
   1152                 [tick.label2.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1153                  for tick in ticks if tick.label2.get_visible()])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1149         """Return lists of bboxes for ticks' label1's and label2's."""
   1150         return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
-> 1151                  for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
   1152                 [tick.label2.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1153                  for tick in ticks if tick.label2.get_visible()])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py in get_window_extent(self, renderer, dpi)
    888             raise RuntimeError('Cannot get window extent w/o renderer')
    889 
--> 890         bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
    891         x, y = self.get_unitless_position()
    892         x, y = self.get_transform().transform_point((x, y))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    289         _, lp_h, lp_d = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(
    290             "lp", self._fontproperties,
--> 291             ismath="TeX" if self.get_usetex() else False)
    292         min_dy = (lp_h - lp_d) * self._linespacing
    293 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
    199             fontsize = prop.get_size_in_points()
    200             w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(
--> 201                 s, fontsize, renderer=self)
    202             return w, h, d
    203 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
    446         else:
    447             # use dviread. It sometimes returns a wrong descent.
--> 448             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
    449             with dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction) as dvi:
    450                 page, = dvi

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
    336                 self._run_checked_subprocess(
    337                     ["latex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "--halt-on-error",
--> 338                      texfile], tex)
    339             for fname in glob.glob(basefile + '*'):
    340                 if not fname.endswith(('dvi', 'tex')):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex)
    306             raise RuntimeError(
    307                 'Failed to process string with tex because {} could not be '
--> 308                 'found'.format(command[0])) from exc
    309         except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
    310             raise RuntimeError(

RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex)
    303                                              cwd=self.texcache,
--> 304                                              stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    305         except FileNotFoundError as exc:

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    394     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 395                **kwargs).stdout
    396 

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    471 
--> 472     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    473         try:

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    774                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 775                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    776         except:

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1177                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
-> 1178                                          startupinfo)
   1179             finally:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    242 
    243     if 'png' in formats:
--> 244         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    245     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    246         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    126 
    127     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 128     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    129     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    130     if fmt == 'svg':

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
   2054                         orientation=orientation,
   2055                         dryrun=True,
-> 2056                         **kwargs)
   2057                     renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
   2058                     bbox_artists = kwargs.pop("bbox_extra_artists", None)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, metadata, pil_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    525 
    526         else:
--> 527             FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    528             renderer = self.get_renderer()
    529             with cbook._setattr_cm(renderer, dpi=self.figure.dpi), \

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    386         self.renderer = self.get_renderer(cleared=True)
    387         with RendererAgg.lock:
--> 388             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    389             # A GUI class may be need to update a window using this draw, so
    390             # don't forget to call the superclass.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     36                 renderer.start_filter()
     37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39         finally:
     40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1707             self.patch.draw(renderer)
   1708             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1709                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   1710 
   1711             renderer.close_group('figure')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    133     if not_composite or not has_images:
    134         for a in artists:
--> 135             a.draw(renderer)
    136     else:
    137         # Composite any adjacent images together

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     36                 renderer.start_filter()
     37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39         finally:
     40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2643             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2644 
-> 2645         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2646 
   2647         renderer.close_group('axes')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    133     if not_composite or not has_images:
    134         for a in artists:
--> 135             a.draw(renderer)
    136     else:
    137         # Composite any adjacent images together

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     36                 renderer.start_filter()
     37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39         finally:
     40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1204         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
   1205         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
-> 1206                                                                 renderer)
   1207 
   1208         for tick in ticks_to_draw:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer)
   1149         """Return lists of bboxes for ticks' label1's and label2's."""
   1150         return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
-> 1151                  for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
   1152                 [tick.label2.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1153                  for tick in ticks if tick.label2.get_visible()])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1149         """Return lists of bboxes for ticks' label1's and label2's."""
   1150         return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
-> 1151                  for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
   1152                 [tick.label2.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1153                  for tick in ticks if tick.label2.get_visible()])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py in get_window_extent(self, renderer, dpi)
    888             raise RuntimeError('Cannot get window extent w/o renderer')
    889 
--> 890         bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
    891         x, y = self.get_unitless_position()
    892         x, y = self.get_transform().transform_point((x, y))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    289         _, lp_h, lp_d = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(
    290             "lp", self._fontproperties,
--> 291             ismath="TeX" if self.get_usetex() else False)
    292         min_dy = (lp_h - lp_d) * self._linespacing
    293 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
    199             fontsize = prop.get_size_in_points()
    200             w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(
--> 201                 s, fontsize, renderer=self)
    202             return w, h, d
    203 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
    446         else:
    447             # use dviread. It sometimes returns a wrong descent.
--> 448             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
    449             with dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction) as dvi:
    450                 page, = dvi

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
    336                 self._run_checked_subprocess(
    337                     ["latex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "--halt-on-error",
--> 338                      texfile], tex)
    339             for fname in glob.glob(basefile + '*'):
    340                 if not fname.endswith(('dvi', 'tex')):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex)
    306             raise RuntimeError(
    307                 'Failed to process string with tex because {} could not be '
--> 308                 'found'.format(command[0])) from exc
    309         except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
    310             raise RuntimeError(

RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found

<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

**Edit 1:**

I have tried running the same code on my homePC which also runs Windows 10, the same Python version and latex version and the code is not throwing an error and it plots everything how it is supposed to be. 
I still need it to work on my Laptop with which I have that issue but I just wanted to state that it surprisingly works on my other PC that seems to have the same settings..

Comment: ```From printing latex in the cmd window in Windows 10 i get ``` Have you tried doing that in anaconda prompt?

Comment: Yeah I get the same results in Anaconda Prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found a solution on my problem..

First I uninstalled Anaconda. I also deleted the folder found in the Users Directory .anaconda3 it was. 
I reinstalled like normal and have run my script. After that I got 2 external windows to install packages from LaTex. (I didn't get them last time)

BUT I also am running BitDefender and when I wanted to install them my AntiVirus Software didn't allow them to download calling it unsafe but not mentioning it. 
I deactivated BitDefender and tried to reproduce the Occasion of the LaTex windows opening.. so I let my script run again and the 2 windows appeared again. 
I now have the packages installed and matplot and everything else is printing just fine now.

**TL;DR:** 
For anyone running into the same problem, it could be that your antivirus Software is preventing jupyter to install the needed packages and therefore you dont have the files needed to plot.